# System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to do a School Management System for practising. But I'm getting exception that i didnt know how to resolve.

Exception That i'm getting;

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SchoolManagementApp.Core.UnitOfWorks.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: SchoolManagementApp.Dal.UnitOfWorks.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.UnitOfWorks.UnitOfWork'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SchoolManagementApp.Core.Repositories.IStudentRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: SchoolManagementApp.Dal.Repositories.StudentRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.Repositories.StudentRepository'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: SchoolManagementApp.Core.Services.IStudentService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: SchoolManagementApp.Service.Services.StudentService': Unable to resolve service for type 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.Repositories.GenericRepository`1[SchoolManagementApp.Core.Models.Student]'.)'

program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IService<>), typeof(Service<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStudentRepository, StudentRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IStudentService, StudentService>();



var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

AppDbContext.cs

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Dal
{
    public class AppDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public AppDbContext()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Lecturer> Lecturers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<LessonOfStudent> LessonOfStudents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ActiveLesson> ActiveLessons { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CollegeDepartment> CollegeDepartments { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CollegeDepartmentsActiveLesson> CollegeDepartmentsActiveLessons { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LessonConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new StudentConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LecturerConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new LessonOfStudentConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ActiveLessonConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CollegeDepartmentConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new CollegeDepartmentsActiveLessonConfiguration());

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            //Todo Configuration read
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DESKTOP-H2SJGIR;Initial Catalog=DbSchoolManagement;Integrated Security=True");
        }
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork.cs

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Dal.UnitOfWorks
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        public UnitOfWork(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public void Commit()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        public async Task CommitAsync()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

IUnitOfWork.cs

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Core.UnitOfWorks
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        Task CommitAsync();
        void Commit();
    }
}
```

IStudentRepository

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Core.Repositories
{
    public interface IStudentRepository : IGenericRepository<Student>
    {
    }
}
```

StudentRepository

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Dal.Repositories
{
    public class StudentRepository : GenericRepository<Student>,IStudentRepository
    {
        public StudentRepository(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Service.cs

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Service.Services
{
    public class Service<T> : IService<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IGenericRepository<T> _repository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public Service(IGenericRepository<T> genericRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _repository = genericRepository;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        //Service methods
```

IStudentService

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Core.Services
{
    public interface IStudentService : IService<Student> { }
}
```

StudentService

```
namespace SchoolManagementApp.Service.Services
{
    public class StudentService : Service<Student>, IStudentService
    {
        private readonly IStudentRepository _studentRepository;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public StudentService(IGenericRepository<Student> genericRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IStudentRepository studentRepository) : base(genericRepository, unitOfWork)
        {
            _studentRepository = studentRepository;
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to read some other stackoverflow threads but that didnt help me to resolve my problem.

Comment: `builder.Services` does not register the AppDbContext. That's why it fails to initialize anything which is dependent on AppDbContext.

Comment: I don't see a call to register DbContext - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.entityframeworkservicecollectionextensions.adddbcontext?view=efcore-7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

> Unable to resolve service for type 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.AppDbContext' while attempting to activate 'SchoolManagementApp.Dal.UnitOfWorks.UnitOfWork'

Your DbContext is not registered in the DI. Check out the [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/) article. Usually you setup you have in `OnConfiguring` on the injection level and provide ctor accepting `DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>`. Something along these lines:

```cs
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    // not needed
    // protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {}
}
```

And registration:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("Data Source=DESKTOP-H2SJGIR;Initial Catalog=DbSchoolManagement;Integrated Security=True")); // better would be reading from config
```

Also check out [Dependency injection in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article.